# Necessary to level up to level 100 for battling?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

This might be another noob question, but is it necessary to level up your pokemon to level 100 to battle (at Battle Maison or Wi-Fi battling). Assuming that your pokemon are fully EV-trained and their levels will be "standardized" to level 50 when battling, would there actually be any difference in stats if your pokemon are higher-leveled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're standardized down/up to level 50 in wi-fi battles, and the Battle Maison will round them down (not up) to level 50. Unless there's a setting to battle without rounding that I'm unaware of, there's no point to leveling over 50 except for NPC fights in-game or to learn moves acquired at level 51+. There's no difference in EV bonuses or other stat changes due to level. I regularly fight with level 100 and level 50 pokemon in battle maison and Wifi, their stats are scaled as if they were both 50.

Comment: For completeness' sake, some Pokémon evolve to their final forms after level 50 (most Dragon-likes, for instance), so technically, leveling them until they evolve WILL increase their stats.